# Voting reversal for smaller tags with few answerers

Tags: discussion, reputation, serial-voting, voting-fraud, voting-correction

Today I received a Voting reversal and after investigating using the reputation-history API, I found that almost all of the votes were for the [`algolia`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/algolia) tag, which only had a couple of active answerers, myself and an Algolia employee for the most part of 2022.

This accounted for 14 posts under the algolia tag only according to the API:

- ([70663654](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70663654), [70655867](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70655867) same main post),
- [70738474](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70738474),
- [70873220](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70873220),
- [70803515](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70803515),
- [71701705](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71701705),
- [71287714](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71287714),
- [74720557](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74720557),
- [74535013](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74535013),
- [72781049](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72781049),
- [72332969](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72332969),
- [71696100](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71696100),
- [74807138](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74807138),
- ([70698761](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70698761) - the upvote I gave and the accept mark were also reversed ,so I reaccepted since the answer actually helped).

The message quotes

> We recently noticed a substantial number of votes on your account to
> or from specific users. While we encourage everyone to upvote great
> posts and downvote bad ones, the motivation for doing so needs to be
> anchored in the merits of the *post*, **not the person who wrote it**.
> Please refrain from targeting specific users when voting.

How should I handle this situation from my end since there is only a handful of answerers? Is my account at risk of suspension if I ever vote for that user's posts again?

Also quoting

> The system has processes in place to detect various types of voting
> between groups of users, so if you know anyone who may be voting for
> your stuff in kind, please ask them to refrain before the system
> detects such activity and takes similar actions on their account.

For small tags like this does that indirectly fall under "voting between groups of users" even though the votes may be for the content and not for the person?

Comment: How exactly did you vote in that tag? Was it many votes in a single day?

Comment: tbh i don't really remember. not much happening in terms of question rate in that tag anyway so i doubt i can do much in a single day

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the "myself and an employee". Are you the employer and you had your employee also patrol that tag? Is that an employee from an affiliated company?  Are the two of you close to each other, network wise? Same timezone maybe? Are you affiliated to that tag in any way?

Comment: @rene nope the other person was an employee. I'm not affiliated with algolia in any way. i only use algolia as a service in my projects. i also personally don't know him

Comment: It is not unheard of that small tags have a higher coincidence rate of cross votes. But we can only speculate what a CM saw in their tooling to conclude the votes needed to be invalidated. I don't think a mod can tell us either, you'll need a staff member to explain before we can give proper guidance. If anything I would hold back votes in that tag for now. I hear [tag:regex] is a cool tag. They need votes too .. ;)

Comment: @rene thanks for the [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) suggestion xD. The [last post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70698761) was the one that gave it away otherwise i would have no clue. so i suspect that the upvotes came from him. what if the upvotes were because they thought my answers were good, i mean why would an employee upvote answers that are bad.  Also is there a way to appeal or ask a staff member to explain as you mentioned above?

Comment: @cmgchess You can use the [contact page](https://stackoverflow.co/company/contact) and link to this meta discussion to ensure an employee sees it. There's a good chance it can be reverted; erroneous voting reversals in small tags or in tight-knit groups happen from time to time.

Comment: This post has been brought to the attention of the employee who performed the original investigation, so this will at least be double-checked.  The response to the original CM escalation didn't elaborate as to the reason they believed the votes to be targeted, and the information moderators have is not conclusive either way (CMs have access to far more detailed information, including being able to see individual votes).

Comment: FWIW I've been bitten by this one before. The voting tools in general don't provide much context so it's easy to miss that votes are made within a small tag (which, anecdotally, is less then 1% of all vote fraud investigations). In my case, it was a handful of users, not just one, and they appeared to be a voting ring. The good news is the votes can be put back if a Community Manager agrees.

Comment: I had something similar on a sister site. I noticed that I only got suspended for "suspicious voting" each time very soon after commenting on a certain site moderator's answers... But even without corruption, I thought that a high concentration of askers or answerers would cause problems with voting flags. (The moderator writes about 30-40% of all site answers)

Comment: @user253751 by the way, if you have concerns about how you've been moderated on any Stack Exchange site, you can always request a review from staff via the [contact form](https://stackoverflow.com/contact).

Comment: @RyanM Indeed I have. Both times the decision has been reversed by staff. I mention it here because it is relevant, because it could trip a naive algorithm even with no wrongdoing on a moderator's part.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Mea culpa. I performed this invalidation, and now I've reversed it.

I can't go into great detail as to what I saw, but I'll admit I was a bit aggressive about what I considered 'vote fraud' in this case. Not by a whole lot - the voting record here bears a few hallmarks of what vote fraud normally looks like. But I was certainly a bit *too* ready to invalidate, and should have given this a second look.

The upside (small consolation) is that I know why this happened, and I'll be updating CM vote fraud investigation tools shortly to hopefully prevent repeats due to the same cause.