# How can a voting correction reach -6060 points?

Tags: support, reputation, serial-voting, voting-correction

Yesterday, a vote correction was applied to my account, and I don't understand how a vote correction could reach -6060 points.

[image]

Does it mean only one person votes for me (without serial voting)? The Pandas community is very small, so I think the same people vote on each other's answers. Currently, there are perhaps less than ten people giving relevant answers on this tag.

Is this an error? I guess it's not an automatic script that detects this. What are the criteria that lead to such a result?

###### Related:

- [Why do I have a reputation change on my reputation page that says "voting corrected"?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed)
- [Unusual Voting Correction: -2033 Reputation Points](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426974/unusual-voting-correction-2033-reputation-points)

Comment: It's 606 upvotes total (or some mixture of up and downvotes). Not necessarily by the same user account as it might have been a voting ring. It *might* have been the same person behind all user accounts but it's even harder to say.

Comment: Maybe another case of this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424189/voting-reversal-for-smaller-tags-with-few-answerers

Comment: I wonder why the votes were reversed.

Comment: I earn between 0 and 150 points per day (accepted answer included and with periods of absence where I earn nothing). So it takes a long time to get 6000 points... The Pandas community is really small compared to Python so there are very few people voting. Even with your explanation, I don't understand the reasons for this decision.

Comment: Appears both you and [mozway](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16343464/mozway?tab=reputation) were "hit" in the event.

Comment: I don't understand how you can have -2.5k in the drop-down but -6k in the full list.

Comment: That's why I took the screenshot... There is an inconsistency! And all my reputation before disappeared in the drop-down list.

Comment: @ThomA indeed, it also happened to me. [It's not the first time](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419983/pretty-big-serial-voting-was-reversed-hit-why-did-it-take-a-long-time-to-occu/419985#comment923627_419985)

Comment: I feel it’s important to point out, the reputation you have lost, were due to votes that were ultimately decided not to be legitimate. Now it’s possible the invalidation of those votes will be reversed. The likelihood of this being a mistake is low.

Comment: @SecurityHound that's understandable, but it would be great to have more transparency on the reasons for the invalidation.

Comment: @mozway & Corralien From the timestamp on the vote invalidations: A) you were both affected by the same overall set of invalidations; B) the vote invalidations were manual, so done by a CM (CMs are the ones that do manual vote invalidations); C) this happened relatively late in the day on Friday. A moderator has contacted the CM who performed the set of vote invalidations and has asked both for more information and for the circumstances surrounding the invalidated votes to be looked into in more detail. I expect we won't hear anything until *at least* US business hours on Monday.

Comment: @mozway - Transparency will be limited as not to expose another user’s privacy even if they broke the rules by casting invalid votes. I suspect it will be limited to “yes, this was valid” or “no, it appears these votes actually were valid”.

Comment: "*Even with your explanation, I don't understand the reasons for this decision.*" voting fraud is voting fraud. Some fraudsters hide their tracks by dispersing votes to other users yet still do that in order to hide who they are really voting for. It might just happen that you were randomly hit by many of their "cover-up" votes. Or not *too* random - you have 5760 answers which means that it's easier to pick an answer than belongs to you vs somebody who has, say, 40 answers. So, it may be that you happened to be a bigger target.

Comment: Re *"The Pandas community is very small"*: But there is a <censored> of <censored> of questions. Why isn't (practically) anything ever closed as a duplicate in that tag?

Comment: @AllanCameron - If you find an excellent answer helpful upvote it, if your upvoting multiple excellent answers from the same person, upvote the absolute best of the best. It’s not difficult to avoid voting the same person contributions multiple times per day.

Comment: @PeterMortensen - That’s due to unhealthy obsession with not closing a question as a duplicate that a minority of the community has for some reason

Comment: It is proven time and time again - subcommunities exist and some of those subcommunities just do not care they are inhabiting a corner of Stack Overflow. Especially under tags which deviate quite a bit from actual programming questions people vote and curate very differently from established doctrine. It's not an unhealthy  obsession, it is essentially just a refusal to commit.

Comment: @PeterMortensen. *"Why isn't (practically) anything ever closed as a duplicate in that tag?"*. Pandas is a data processing library. There are a large number of functions available but each problem often requires different algorithms to perform well because the data is never formatted the same way. It's the same thing for the PySpark or Scikit-Learn communities.
Of course when the answer requires a single Pandas function the question is closed. I don't find this unhealthy (otherwise I have nothing more to do on StackOverflow).
My only goal is to help people become better at Pandas.

Comment: I have no reason to hide if I vote very often for answers from Mozway, PandaKim, Timeless, Nick, Sammywemmy, AndrejKesely, etc because they are the best answers. Producing a high-performance and functional response in Pandas is not an easy task.

Comment: @SecurityHound what you are suggesting is that I should reign in voting for people who are prolific in writing good answers. In practice, this is what I have done after being rebuked by a voting correction - I like this community and want to follow its rules. But the community's rules are also that I should vote for answers entirely according to whether they are good / helpful, _irrespective_ of who the answerer is. I now find myself in the situation of _not_ upvoting answers I would normally upvote because of the person who wrote them, because I worry the CMs will think it's a voting ring :/

Comment: did either of you receive a notification that your own votes were reversed? the notifications for your votes being reversed and voting corrected due to a reversal are two different things. I don't understand why you're so concerned about votes that you yourself are casting if you haven't received such a warning.

Comment: @KevinB I didn't receive a notification, and I have no idea whether the other user did. I noticed that my rep and the other user's rep were corrected at the same time and by the same amount, so I inferred that this was a correction for unwelcome mutual voting, and that was enough to deter me (like I say, I don't want to break any rules or violate any norms). The other user isn't currently active on the site, so it doesn't make any difference to how I vote now. It's just difficult in some cases to tell the difference between genuine fraud and very active users who appreciate each others answers

Comment: @ThomA I also lost 140 points in that reversal. I have about 1/20 of the number of posts that mozway and Corralien have in that tag so I guess it's about the right ratio.

Comment: I'm in the same situation as AllanCameron. @Nick's comment clearly proves that there is no mutual vote with Mozway but as I said there are few people who give good answers on Pandas. It is therefore normal to observe that we vote among ourselves (without any fraud or agreement between us). I don't understand what the problem is and the lack of transparency is also a problem!

Comment: I don't see why there is this huge discussion about prolific contributors voting for other prolific contributors when the most likely explanation is that a completely different party was committing voting fraud. As @KevinB said - you'd have received some sort of notification if the invalidation targetted your own votes. If you haven't, then you're not considered to have committed voting fraud.

Comment: @VLAZ because it seems so unlikely this is coincidence. Pandas apparently has the unique situation where there are only a few people actively answering a great many questions. Those few will naturally form that subcommunity I mentioned, when they inevitable start following each other's lead. And thus also perhaps... unknowingly and unwillingly form what the site thinks is a voting ring. Definitely more interesting an idea than that it is again the league of shadows. And so I am not surprised it is being discussed, whether it is true or not.

Comment: @Gimby A third party voting ring would also be likely to vote a lot on prolific users. In fact, we have very explicit evidence it has happened in the past. The fact that the voting corrections happened simultaneously is *exceptionally likely* to be because the fraudulent third party was found out and all their votes were invalidated. At the same time, against all other users. Occam's Razor points me to a third party being the most likely explanation. Yet, users here are trying to pin this on mutual voting when many of the details don't match up for that and require more explanation for why.

Comment: @VLAZ.I just want some transparency. When we take away 6000 points (5% of my reputation) from an active user (so useful to the community I hope), we give an explanation... This is even more true when there are several of us... Why none MOD or CM sends us a clear message about this operation? Why has Jezrael (#2 Pandas, #6 SO in 2023) the most active user of the Pandas community and the site (30,000 responses in 10 years) not undergone any vote correction? Why just Mozway (#1 Pandas, #2 SO in 2023) and me (#3 Pandas, #19 SO in 2023). I just want to understand why... Is that bad?

Comment: @Corralien I never said that the question is bad. I objected to the the almost conspiracy-theory level discussion that seemed to be veering into witch hunt territory. I'd appreciate not using loaded questions to try and put a spin on what I've said.

Comment: @VLAZ you're being too rational :) Your question was "why is this being discussed?" - interesting things trump rational things.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In this case, an investigation of suspicious voting by an unrelated user (*i.e.* none of the users who were impacted by the voting correction) brought attention to a collection of voting patterns which resulted in a significant number of votes being invalidated.

Diamond Moderators have access to tooling which allows us to identify patterns of votes that may be suspicious. This allows us to find and identify voting fraud and apply appropriate consequences for those who violate the rules. However, on Stack Exchange up and down votes are considered private, so there is a balance which is maintained between giving moderators enough information to identify suspicious patterns *without* revealing exactly which posts were voted on by a given user.

In order for many cases of voting fraud to be resolved, moderators work with Community Managers (Stack Exchange staff) who also use a set of tools to determine and invalidate votes that are considered a violation of the rules. In some cases, including this one, normal voting patterns can look "suspicious" because of how the voting data is summarised by our tools.

After following up with the Community Manager (CM) who performed the initial invalidation, and a subsequent re-examination of votes, it was determined that too many votes were invalidated in this case. As a result, a large portion of invalidated votes (the majority) have now been restored. The voting correction is now impacting only a limited set of votes and the invalidation entry has been updated to reflect that:

[image: reversal -140 Voting corrected]

Please note that this follow up with the CM would have occurred whether or not a meta post was made about this invalidation. We take voting invalidations very seriously and we work hard to ensure that only fraudulent votes are invalidated. This process can sometimes take several days to resolve based on CM availability, however, this case has now been handled.

Comment: Thanks Henry. I hope your answer will help other users in the same situation. So I understand that even when there are no explanatory messages, the moderators are studying the issue. So you just have to wait (at least a week?) before contacting the moderation team. Thanks to all the moderators and CMs for their work.

Comment: @Corralien [6 to 8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514) ....

Comment: @Corralien This does happen [from time to time](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/408756/2370483) unfortunately, and may be exacerbated by the recent staff changes (where CMs not as familiar with this process are now using the tools on a regular basis). The tools there often require some learned intuition to make determinations.